# NoTextEdit ShapeLock is not working - OpenXML SDK

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to make a TextBox locked by using OpenXML SDK. I've tried this method but the TextBox NoTextEdit is not working.

```
public DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape GenerateShape(string StrText)
{
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape shape1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualShapeProperties nonVisualShapeProperties1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualShapeProperties();
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualDrawingProperties nonVisualDrawingProperties1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)3U, Name = "ID",Hidden=true ,Description="Do not Remove" ,MCAttributes=null };

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties nonVisualShapeDrawingProperties1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties();
    Drawing.ShapeLocks shapeLocks1 = new Drawing.ShapeLocks() { NoTextEdit = true, NoGrouping = true,NoMove=true,NoSelection=true,NoEditPoints=true ,NoAdjustHandles=true ,NoRotation=true,NoChangeArrowheads=true,NoChangeAspect=true,NoChangeShapeType=true,NoResize=true};

    nonVisualShapeDrawingProperties1.Append(shapeLocks1);

    ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties1 = new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties();
    PlaceholderShape placeholderShape1 = new PlaceholderShape() { Type = PlaceholderValues.SubTitle, Index = (UInt32Value)1U   };

    applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties1.Append(placeholderShape1);

    nonVisualShapeProperties1.Append(nonVisualDrawingProperties1);
    nonVisualShapeProperties1.Append(nonVisualShapeDrawingProperties1);
    nonVisualShapeProperties1.Append(applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties1);
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.ShapeProperties shapeProperties1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.ShapeProperties();

    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.TextBody textBody1 = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.TextBody();
    Drawing.BodyProperties bodyProperties1 = new Drawing.BodyProperties();
    Drawing.ListStyle listStyle1 = new Drawing.ListStyle();
    Drawing.TextShape shp = new Drawing.TextShape();

    Drawing.Paragraph paragraph1 = new Drawing.Paragraph();
    Drawing.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties1 = new Drawing.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "en-US" ,Dirty=false };
    paragraph1.Append(GenerateRun(StrText));
    paragraph1.Append(endParagraphRunProperties1);

    textBody1.Append(bodyProperties1);
    textBody1.Append(listStyle1);
    textBody1.Append(paragraph1);

    shape1.Append(nonVisualShapeProperties1);
    shape1.Append(shapeProperties1);
    shape1.Append(textBody1);
    return shape1;
}
public Drawing.Run GenerateRun(string StrText)
{

    Drawing.Run run1 = new Drawing.Run();

    Drawing.RunProperties runProperties1 = new Drawing.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", Dirty = false  };
    runProperties1.SetAttribute(new OpenXmlAttribute("", "smtClean", "", "0"));
    Drawing.Text text1 = new Drawing.Text();
    text1.Text = StrText;
    Drawing.SolidFill solidFill2 = new Drawing.SolidFill();
    Drawing.SchemeColor schemeColor = new Drawing.SchemeColor();

    string y = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent.ToArgb().ToString("X");
    Drawing.RgbColorModelHex rgbColorModelHex2 = new Drawing.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = "FFFFFF" };//Set Font-Color to Blue (Hex "0070C0").

    solidFill2.Append(rgbColorModelHex2);
    runProperties1.Append(solidFill2);


    Color color = new Color() { Val = "365F91", ThemeColor = ThemeColorValues.Accent1, ThemeShade = "BF" };
    run1.Append(runProperties1);
    run1.Append(text1);

    return run1;

}
```

Everything works fine except editing. **Still the user can edit the TextBox values by double clicking it**. How can I avoid this ?

Is there any permanent solution to prevent editing ? Please help me to find a better solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to do it in the PowerPoint application user interface? If not, then Open XML cannot do it... If yes, you can create a small, sample presentation and view it in the Open XML SDK Productivity Tool to see how to code it.

Comment: @CindyMeister While googling I found some third party applications could do it. If they can protect the text from editing, then there must be some way. and Thank you for the suggestions. If any other thoughts please share it might be very helpful to my research . :)

Comment: and in MS documentation https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/prevent-or-allow-changes-to-shapes-e65decf4-0eed-4fd6-a7d9-b286abcbc7eb  they specify how to Lock a shape. But unfortunately in my system there is no option like that.

Comment: The article to which you link is for VISIO - it says so right at the start - and not for PowerPoint.

Comment: @CindyMeister ok. Thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By researching and communications with the MVP team I've pointed out that there is no way to Protect the TextBox from editing.
As  *Cindy Meister* mentioned in the comments,

> Are you able to do it in the PowerPoint application user interface? If not, then Open XML cannot do it... If yes, you can.

If you do not want to text to be changed , Just change it as image then lock that by using `NoSelection=true/1` and `NoMove=true/1` properties. If you enable these properties the user can't either delete nor change it's position.

For your ref: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-mso_windows8-mso_2016/shape-lock-is-not-working/c1705b55-d2aa-4adb-b538-574ed2fc8eca?tm=1579265435636&page=1&rtAction=1579495439869